# How to put a line and a note under a certain column in tables?

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularx

There is this table in a textbook I'm reading,

[image]

I have tried to recreate it and almost succeeded except for this small part where an hline is added below the last column and a note. Here is my attempt and code,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]                    
\centering                         
\begin{tabular}{c c @{\hskip 0.8cm} c @{\hskip 0.8cm} c c c @{\hskip 0.8cm} c}                                                                     
$q_A$ & $\Omega_A$ & $P(q_A)$ & $q_B$ & $\Omega_B$ & $\Omega_{Total} = \Omega_A \Omega_B $ \\ [0.5ex]      
\hline                               
0 & 1 & 0.42  & 7    & 330 & 330 \\  
1 & 1 & 0.27  & 6    & 210 & 210 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0.16  & 5    & 126 & 126 \\ 
3 & 1 & 0.09  & 4    & 70  & 70  \\ 
4 & 1 & 0.04  & 3    & 35  & 35  \\
5 & 1 & 0.02  & 2    & 15  & 15  \\
6 & 1 & 0.006 & 1    & 5   & 5   \\
7 & 1 & 0.001 & 0    & 1   & 1   \\[1ex]                                   
\end{tabular} 
\label{table:1}                           
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Update:

Here is a new attempt,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]                    
\centering                         
\begin{tabular}{c c @{\hskip 0.8cm} c @{\hskip 0.8cm} c c c @{\hskip 0.8cm} c}                                                                     
$q_A$ & $\Omega_A$ & $P(q_A)$ & $q_B$ & $\Omega_B$ & $\Omega_{Total} = \Omega_A \Omega_B $ \\ [0.5ex]      
\hline                               
0 & 1 & 0.42  & 7    & 330 & 330 \\  
1 & 1 & 0.27  & 6    & 210 & 210 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0.16  & 5    & 126 & 126 \\ 
3 & 1 & 0.09  & 4    & 70  & 70  \\ 
4 & 1 & 0.04  & 3    & 35  & 35  \\
5 & 1 & 0.02  & 2    & 15  & 15  \\
6 & 1 & 0.006 & 1    & 5   & 5   \\
7 & 1 & 0.001 & 0    & 1   & 1   \\[1ex]
\cline{6-6}
  &   &       &      &     & 792 = $\binom{7+6-1}{7}$                                   
\end{tabular} 
\label{table:1}                           
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Please add the few missing lines which makes your code compile, when we copy it. Thank you

Comment: Oh yes sorry give me a second

Comment: Great. No problem: it‘s easier now for everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the issue with your code is that it specifies the table to have seven columns, while it has only six. This causes a noticeable "overhang" of the horizontal lines.

Fixing this issue, switching from a `tabular` to an `array` environment (since the contents are all math-y), using `\midrule` instead of `\hline`, and -- last but not least -- employing a `\cmidrule` directive instead of `\cline` produces this result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]                    
\[
\begin{array}{@{}  c c @{\hspace{8mm}} c 
   @{\hspace{8mm}} c c @{\hspace{6mm}} c @{}}                                                                     
q_A & \Omega_A & P(q_A) & q_B & \Omega_B & 
\Omega_{\mathrm{Total}}=\Omega_A \Omega_B \\       
\midrule                               
0 & 1 & 0.42  & 7    & 330 & 330 \\  
1 & 1 & 0.27  & 6    & 210 & 210 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0.16  & 5    & 126 & 126 \\ 
3 & 1 & 0.09  & 4    & 70  & 70 \\ 
4 & 1 & 0.04  & 3    & 35  & 35 \\
5 & 1 & 0.02  & 2    & 15  & 15 \\
6 & 1 & 0.006 & 1    & 5   & 5  \\
7 & 1 & 0.001 & 0    & 1   & 1  \\
\cmidrule(l){6-6}             
 & & & & & 792 = \binom{7+6-1}{7}
\end{array}
\]
%\label{table:1} % no point in having \label without \caption
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```